# Tinder API Authentication Token Retrieval

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm working on implementing an AI bot that uses DialogueFlow to have intelligent conversations with my matches.  The link to the GitHub package that contains all the scripts is here: https://github.com/nathan-149/tinderbot

I am at this point just trying to get the authentication token in order to hook up the bot, here is the code for the first script which is supposed to return the API token:

```
import json

import requests

CODE_REQUEST_URL = "https://api.gotinder.com/v2/auth/sms/send?auth_type=sms"
CODE_VALIDATE_URL = "https://api.gotinder.com/v2/auth/sms/validate?auth_type=sms"
TOKEN_URL = "https://api.gotinder.com/v2/auth/login/sms"

HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Tinder/11.4.0 (iPhone; iOS 12.4.1; Scale/2.00)', 'content-type': 'application/json'}

def send_otp_code(phone_number):
    data = {'phone_number': phone_number}
    r = requests.post(CODE_REQUEST_URL, headers=HEADERS, data=json.dumps(data), verify=False)
    print(r.url)
    response = r.json()
    if(response.get("data")['sms_sent'] == False):
        return False
    else:
        return True

def get_refresh_token(otp_code, phone_number):
    data = {'otp_code': otp_code, 'phone_number': phone_number}
    r = requests.post(CODE_VALIDATE_URL, headers=HEADERS, data=json.dumps(data), verify=False)
    print(r.url)
    response = r.json()
    if(response.get("data")["validated"] == False):
        return False
    else:
        return response.get("data")["refresh_token"]
    
def get_api_token(refresh_token):
    data = {'refresh_token': refresh_token }
    r = requests.post(TOKEN_URL, headers=HEADERS, data=json.dumps(data), verify=False)
    print(r.url)
    response = r.json()
    return response.get("data")["api_token"]

phone_number = input("Please enter your phone number under the international format (country code + number): ")
log_code = send_otp_code(phone_number)
otp_code = input("Please enter the code you've received by sms: ")
refresh_token = get_refresh_token(otp_code, phone_number)
print("Here is your Tinder token: " + str(get_api_token(refresh_token)))
```

Unfortunately when I run the code and put in the access code from my phone I get the following error:

```
  File "c:\Users\MIS-l\OneDrive\Desktop\tinderbot-master\phone_auth_token.py", line 44, in <module>
    print("Here is your Tinder token: " + get_api_token(refresh_token))
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\MIS-l\OneDrive\Desktop\tinderbot-master\phone_auth_token.py", line 37, in get_api_token
    return response.get("data")["api_token"]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I have tried accessing the API links at the top of the beginning of the script but I just get Error 404 for all of them.

What can I do to get the access token?

Comment: The reason you're getting this error ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable``` is because it's returning a 404 status code. In short , I think the endpoint has changed.

Answer (score 1):

To make things simple, the error you are having below just means that this api endpoint `TOKEN_URL = "https://api.gotinder.com/v2/auth/login/sms"` **no longer works**, in fact all of those endpoints no longer works. It's because tinder has changed its new way of SMS Authentication (which is v3) and there is nothing we can do about that.

```
    return response.get("data")["api_token"]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

*Solution*

Credits to [jimtje](https://github.com/jimtje) who created this [PR](https://github.com/fbessez/Tinder/pull/117)

The solution lies [here](https://github.com/fbessez/Tinder/pull/117/files) (trust me I have tried this as well and it works). Simply copy the following files `authgateway.py` & `sms_auth_v3.py` and put them in one folder (If you can copy the branch to make your life easier that is fine as well) (please do make sure that you install all dependencies needed in the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/fbessez/Tinder/pull/117/files#diff-4d7c51b1efe9043e44439a949dfd92e5827321b34082903477fd04876edb7552)). One thing to take note, when I first tried it didn't work and after days of figuring it out I noticed that it was all because of the headers. To cut it short kindly change the headers to this [comment here](https://github.com/fbessez/Tinder/pull/117#issuecomment-1777600639).

Once you've done all of that. Simply run `sms_auth_v3.py` and just follow the authentication process by

1. Submitting your phone number. In which you will receive an OTP code.
2. Submitting the OTP code sent to your phone number
3. You'll receive another OTP in your email where it is associated to your tinder account
4. Submit the email OTP
5. Done! you'll finally have the `refresh token` and `auth token`